# Installed gnomne-doc-utils but another program still says the version isn't new enough

Tags: command-line, 18.04, apt

This is on Lubuntu 18.04. Below you can see the version of gnome-doc-utils apparently isn't recent enough. How can I install the most recent version? I assumed it would do that by default.

I tried again, running `sudo apt-get update` beforehand, then rerunning `sudo apt-get install gnome-doc-utils` and `./configure && make && make install` but the same error was produced.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-doc-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdav1d2 libllvm8 libllvm8:i386 linux-headers-4.15.0-72
  linux-headers-4.15.0-72-generic linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-72-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-72-generic
  mokutil shim
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libxml2-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-doc-utils libxml2-utils
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 323 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,799 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxml2-utils amd64 2.9.4+dfsg1-6.1ubuntu1.3 [35.9 kB]
Get:2 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 gnome-doc-utils all 0.20.10-4 [287 kB]
Fetched 323 kB in 2s (140 kB/s)          
Selecting previously unselected package libxml2-utils.
(Reading database ... 273195 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libxml2-utils_2.9.4+dfsg1-6.1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxml2-utils (2.9.4+dfsg1-6.1ubuntu1.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-doc-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-doc-utils_0.20.10-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-doc-utils (0.20.10-4) ...
Setting up libxml2-utils (2.9.4+dfsg1-6.1ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up gnome-doc-utils (0.20.10-4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...

owner@G700:~/Downloads/long_term/ignuit-2.24.3$ ./configure && make && make install
<about 50 checks removed>

checking gnome-doc-utils >= 0.3.2... no
configure: error: gnome-doc-utils >= 0.3.2 not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install more [dependencies](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/app-misc/ignuit/ignuit-2.24.3.ebuild)

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-doc-utils libgnomeui-dev libglade2-dev \
libxslt1-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev rarian-compat
```

and then retry:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://dev.gentoo.org/~leio/distfiles/ignuit-2.24.3.testing.tar.gz
tar -xf ignuit-2.24.3.testing.tar.gz
cd ignuit-2.24.3.testing/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and enjoy:

> ```
> $ ignuit --version
> GNOME ignuit 2.24.3.testing
> ```